# getting parse initialization error while unit testing activity with Robolectrics framework and eclipse

Tags: android-activity

I am unit testing activity with Robolectric framework and getting the following error of parse initialization error.

MyActivity.java

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // hide action bar 
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    //Checking Current User
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) 
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, ViewPagerStyleLandingActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        WelcomeActivity.this.finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.actvity_welcome);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SIGNUP_CHECK_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.PREF_KEY_FIRST_RUN, false);
    editor.commit();

     Button loginbut=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
       Button registerbut=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

           loginbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i=new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
           });
            registerbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i=new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }); 
}
```

}

and have made the test case as

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class WelcomeActivityTest {

private WelcomeActivity activity;
private Button loginbut;
@Before 
public void setup()  {

 activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(WelcomeActivity.class).create().get(); 
 loginbut = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);`}


@Test
  public void checkActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
  }



  @Test
  public void shouldHaveButtonThatSaysAudit() throws Exception{
    assertThat((String) loginbut.getText(), equalTo("Login"));
  }

  @Test
  public void pressingLaunchButtonForSecondActivity() throws Exception {
    String resultValue = "Testing Text";
    assertNotNull(loginbut);
    loginbut.performClick();
    Intent startedIntent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
    assertThat(resultValue, equalTo(startedIntent.getStringExtra("result")));
    }

  private ShadowContextWrapper shadowOf(WelcomeActivity activity2) {
    return null;
}

@After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    // Nothing Here
  } 
}
```

now getting the error
when running with jUnit

[image: the error is as follows]